# Signal Generation with duration in VHDL?

Tags: signal, vhdl, clock

Im writing a signal generator in VHDL and I would like to set the duration of the signal generated to 75ms, it is an out signal and my clock is 100 MHz, I would be glad if you can help!

Comment: What have you written so far, and what help do you need with it?

Comment: @BrianDrummond It is actually an auto generated code by DDS_Core I would like the duration of `sine : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(14 DOWNTO 0);` 75ms

Comment: Are you going to use PWM or a DAC? What resolution are you looking to achieve? What range of frequencies?

Comment: @Andyaka I want the dtmf keypad frequencies, will generate a high and low frequency, to signal which key was pressed to an AC'97 Codec and then from Codec to Analyzer. I didn't understand the PWN/DAC part...

Comment: How often are you planning on updating the output? If you update several times within 75ms, will those values be lost or do you want each value written to have a 75ms duration? The latter could be accomplished with a FIFO and a small Finite State Machine with a 75ms counter clocked off of the 100Mhz clock.

Comment: @Peter a key press will trigger each signal generation, so as much as someone presses the key. I would like each value to be as along as 75ms and the values will be transferred to a codec and then to an analyzer. The dtmf analyzer in the end will tell from the frequencies, which key was pressed.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand a little more. So the user presses a key and you'd like to generate a sine wave of varying frequency for 75ms as 15bit digital signal on the output. The user can't physically move their finger quickly enough from the first key to the second key within 75ms, so the output for the first key will run out before the second key is pressed. Have I accurately described your system?

Comment: Here's a hint: You're using DDS to generate your tones -- what would happen if you were to set a DDS to a frequency of 13.333 Hz?

Comment: @Peter More less yes!

Comment: @DaveTweed Highest frequency will be 1633 Hz.

Comment: For the 75ms part of it, it sounds like you need a finite state machine made up of an idle and counter state. The counter state would implement the 75ms duration. If you need more help, I'll have to see what you've implemented so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a separate process for generating a mono-shot of 75ms delay triggered by key press. Then use this mono-shot signal in the sensitivity list of the process in which the output signal is assigned with required values. The code will be something like:

```
process(any_key) -- process for mono-shot of 75ms delay
begin  
  if (any_key = '1') then
    temp <= '1';
    wait for 75ms; -- replace with a counter
    temp <= '0';
  end if;
end process;

process(temp) 
begin
    if (temp = '1') then
        out <= required_signal;
    else
        out <= '0';
    end if;
end process;
```

Before synthesizing you have to replace that `wait for` statement with a counter to implement `75ms` delay.